# Issue with "Email Feature" in my project which is made with Symfony2 Framework

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, sendmail, web-hosting

Previously, this application has built and been hosted in Amazon by initial authors. Then after, because of some issues with Amazon changed to Godaddy, the problem here is sending email, forgot-password-mails etc and even uploading images are not working when the application is in Godaddy and was working perfectly when its was in Amazon.

I googled some info about AWS & understood that the authors installed the aws-sdk-php 3rd party in vendor folder of my symfony application & used some buckets for storing etc...

So in application I found some variables of AWS in config.yml, config.yml, parameters.yml. Simply I've commented all these variables and changed the code in **parameters.yml**

```
from_email_address: xxxxxx@xxx.com
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
mailer_user: xxxxxxx
mailer_password:  xxxxxxx
locale: en
secret: xxxxxxxxx
debug_toolbar: true
debug_redirects: false
use_assetic_controller: true
amazon_s3.key: xxxxxxx
amazon_s3.secret: xxxxxx  
amazon_s3.region: eu-west-1
```

to

```
from_email_address: xxxxx@xx.com
# mailer_transport: smtp
# mailer_host: email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
# mailer_user: xxxxxxx
# mailer_password:  xxxxxxx
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: xxxxx@xx.com
mailer_password: xxxxxxx
locale: en
secret: xxxxxxx
# debug_toolbar: true
# debug_redirects: false
# use_assetic_controller: true
# amazon_s3.key: xxxxxxx
# amazon_s3.secret: xxxxxxx  
# amazon_s3.region: eu-west-1
```

and also I have changed my code in controller from

```
$maildata = array(
                "name" => $userinfo->getFullname(),
                "email" => $userinfo->getEmail(),
                "code" => md5($userinfo->getUid())
            );
            $email = $this->get('emails_handler');
            $subject = "Quotemyhouse.com account verification request.";
            $message = $this->renderView('AppBundle:Emails:welcomeEmail.html.twig', $maildata);
            $email->sendEmail($userinfo->getEmail(), $subject, $message);
```

to

```
$maildata = array(
                "name" => $userinfo->getFullname(),
                "email" => $userinfo->getEmail(),
                "code" => md5($userinfo->getUid())
            );


           $message = $this->renderView('AppBundle:Emails:welcomeEmail.html.twig', $maildata);
           $Subject = "Quotemyhouse.com account verification request.";
            $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
               ->setSubject($Subject)
               ->setFrom($userinfo->getFullname())
               ->setTo($userinfo->getEmail())
               ->setBody($message,'text/html');
            $this->get('mailer')->send($msg);
```

the above changed details in **config.yml** & **parameters.yml** are working with a sample email sending project in localhost.

So I hope you understood the issue I'm facing... 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I expect all smtp configurations in your GoDaddy account is working. In goDaddy mail functions, hostname you have to keep "localhost". So instead of

```
mailer_host: email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

use `mailer_host:localhost`

Some cases you don't require to give `mailer_user` and `mailer_password`. But that you have to do try and trial.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your reply...
          I've changed my code according to your comments and tried with all the trials like giving null to mailer_user, mailer_password & even tried by removing those fields in both parameters.yml & config.yml, but still its not working...

Comment: Presently the entire thing is working perfectly in localhost with my symfony application, but whereas in server its not !

Can I use these gmail details when I'm running in live hosted server? will they work?

Are gmail details are only for localhost?

Comment: swift mailer section in **config.yml** :

   ` # Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
   # encryption: tls
    spool:     { type: memory }
    #for Gmail
    encryption: ssl 
    auth_mode: login`

Comment: &


in **Parameters.yml** :

    from_email_address: abhinav@omkieitsolutions.com
    
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: testing.trial15@gmail.com
    mailer_password: Omkietesting
    locale: en
    secret: quotemyhouse
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
    use_assetic_controller: true

Comment: I think PHPmailer is for corePHP projects, but I'm using a framework right,    can I use that?





then I think I should transfer all corePHP libraries to my symfony project

Comment: I'm using a new gmail ID (which does'nt have security levels) with its password sending to another gmail ID.

Comment: So we completely going on wrong direction. If you want to use gmail for sending email, you had the configuration in your script. I was expecting your own mailhost you are using in GoDaddy.  Use the answer of this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086476/send-mail-through-smtp-gmail-com-in-symfony-2-using-swiftmailer  @AbhinavCh

Comment: Yes Thomas, according to the changes in answer of above link : working fine in localhost but showing an error when I running in Live Server and the error is : ** 
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException
**

Comment: You login into gmail and allow external connection. https://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/sending-with-gmail-doesnt-work/  this link will do. @AbhinavCh

Comment: I think you must have got a mail telling that a unknown access is blocked in your gmail. @AbhinavCh

Comment: @AbhinavCh : Try to send mail with normal php code and test your all connections are fine.

Comment: Many more thanks for your help Thomas. The problem has been resolved. Actually the Gmail parameters are not working in Live, but when I change the parameters with my project's Godaddy account Email parameters its working...

Answer (score 0):

Atlast got the solution for the issue... the problem may be with Gmail parameters in live or may be Gmail mailer parameters are only for localhost.. I dont know

```
Just I've changed the parameters with my Godaddy Account Email paramaeters (which we can find by logging into C-panel of respective account in  Godaddy).
```

There are two types of details present in that Account/Email page of Godaddy, use the recommended SSL parameters which will be on leftside.

Thank you.